# Buddypress: Add step in Group Creation process

Tags: php, buddypress

I want to conditionally add a step in the Group Creation wizard of Buddypress / Buddyboss.
In step 2 my form asks for a specific field (via a Select-box with the HTML name "group-types[]").

Whenever a specific group type is clicked and the user clicks "next step", I want to add a new step inbetween conditionally on the group type field.

I found this code:
https://gist.github.com/shanebp/c9cdde9443bdeab9b4ca

It works, but there are two things:
I'm not sure where exactly to "ask" the already made settings for the group in the creation wizard and unfortunately the settings-page "Ville" is added at the end.

I tried to set a "position"-element in the $arg which is passed to parent::init( $args ); but this is not accepted.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*ville*  is an arbitrary  term. I've updated the gist to use *test*. Replace it with whatever you want. The *Test* step will appear after the *Settings* step and will check for any group types selected in the *Settings* step.

[Updated gist](https://gist.github.com/shanebp/c9cdde9443bdeab9b4ca).

You can get all the group type data as an object:

```
$group_types = bp_groups_get_group_type( $group_id, false );
    
if ( is_array( $group_types ) ) {
    
    foreach ( $group_types as $group_type ) {

        $group_object = bp_groups_get_group_type_object( $group_type );
        var_dump( $group_object );

    }
    
} else {

    $group_object = bp_groups_get_group_type_object( $group_types );
    var_dump( $group_object );
    
}
```

Comment: That sounds good, thanks. One more thing: bp_groups_get_group_type() returns the slugs of the Groups for that particular group - can one also display the Group Labels/Names (which are shown as labels in the Group Type Dropdown in Step 2)?

Comment: Answer edited to show how to get data, including the name, for each selected group type.

Comment: Amazing, this helps a lot to understand the API of BP. I'll follow up on this one :) Thanks!